# Run dotnet console application interactively in Ubuntu at startup

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, arm

I have a basic dotnet core console application which displays the contents of an Azure Storage Queue as a console output. It's a POC for something I want to build.

I want to run this on a small Ubuntu-driven device with an integrated screen. (https://www.unihiker.com/) - my Linux knowledge is limited.

I've installed dotnet ok, and I can execute the DLL fine from a remote terminal session.
I can run xterm -e which does display the console output on the attached screen.

I want the application to run on startup, displaying the contents of the console output on the screen itself, but I'm getting stuck.

I've tried creating a startup script and calling it from chron on startup, but this did not work.

I have now registered the app as a service by following [this guide](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-run-a-dotnet-core-console-app-as-a-service-using-systemd-on-linux), and added

```
systemctl start ConsoleGUI
```

To the .xsessionrc file.

Nothing appears on the screen, however, if I call `systemctl status ConsoleGUI`, I can see the output I expect.

I'm nearly there, but I am at the end of my Linux talent.

How can I get my dotnet console app to run interactively (on the local screen) on start-up

This is my service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Console GUI

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/.dotnet/xterm -e dotnet /media/sda1/LiveGui/LiveConsoleGui.dll
SyslogIdentifier=ConsoleGUI
    
User=root
    
Environment=DOTNET_ROOT=/root/.dotnet

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: The service in Linux is being started by the OS and any output would go to the console screen.  You would have to enable the console screen to see the output.  I've done this on a Raspberry and the console serial port.  I had to buy a AdaFruit adapter which converted the serial port to USB and then connected to a Windows machine.  Normally when you do a remote connection to a Linux you use RSH which is a TCP connection over ethernet.  If you want you server to output to a TCP connection you would need to redirect the console standard output to a TCP port.